# How do I enable more than 8-bit colors in Terminal.app?

Tags: macos

In the Vim and Emacs terminal apps, the color schemes look horrid. How do I enable the colors to be as vibrant as the GUI version (or more than 8 colors for that matter)?

Should I just give up, and move over to their respective GUI applications? And if so, which?

Comment: is the problem 8 colors or 8-bit colors? Your title and body of the question don't agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have **more** colors in the terminal, because there are only ANSI codes for 8 colors (16 if you count bold/light).  If you want to customize the colors, you can use the TerminalColours plugin from http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/11/01/customising-colours-in-leopard-terminal

Personally, I prefer to use the so-called Carbon Emacs on my Mac.  There are several builds available; Google is your friend.  I get mine from http://www.porkrind.org/emacs/

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly being inhibited by the fact you are running in a VT100/WhateverItsCalled compatible terminal and it just doesn't *have* more than about 16 foreground and 16 background colours.   If it did, the lovely library "CaCa" ( ColourAsciiColourArt ) would be much more pleasing to watch than it is.

If you want more colours, you simply have to use more modern technology, and this generally means using X ( unless your loving pain and want to use directfb/framebuffer/svgalib ).

For vim, there is GVim ( GTK+Vim ). Emacs GUI version however displeases me much, but I'm not an emacs user.

Answer (score 0):

[Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) and [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)